# file empty after upload in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to save a beforehand created pdf file to my django model in model's save method:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):    
    pdf_file = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs',blank=True, null=True)
```

And my mdoel save:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

     #create the file at pdf_path with fpdf

     self.pdf_file.save("myfile.pdf" , open(pdf_path, "r", encoding='ISO8859-2'), save=False)  
     super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

There is no errors, the file is created at pdf_path and is a 5 page file with content. There is also a file uploaded into the django database but it is an empty 5 page pdf file.

Comment: fpdf uses ISO8859-2 for encoding. I changed this bzut the problem remains the same